# How can I convert this hash into workable JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, internet-explorer, hash

IE10 is returning parameters in what looks like a double conversion to JSON :

```
=> {"{\"statementId\":"=>
  {"\"b3dsecret9-bsecret741-23secreta806c\""=>
    {",\"Content-Type\":"=>
      {"\"application/json\""=>
        {",\"content\":"=>
          {"\"{\\\"context\\\":{\\\"registration\\\":\\\"27\\\",\\\"contextActivities\\\":{\\\"parent\\\":{\\\"id\\\":\\\"6LHIJumrnmV_course_id\\\"},\\\"grouping\\\":{\\\"id\\\":\\\"6LHIJumrnmV_course_id\\\"}}},\\\"actor\\\":213,\\\"verb\\\":\\\"attempted\\\",\\\"object\\\":{\\\"id\\\":\\\"6LHIJumrnmV_course_id\\\",\\\"definition\\\":{\\\"name\\\":{\\\"und\\\":\\\"\\\"},\\\"type\\\":\\\"Course\\\",\\\"description\\\":{\\\"und\\\":\\\"\\\"}}}}\""=>
            {",\"registration\":"=>
              {"\"27\""=>
                {",\"AWSAccessKeyId\":"=>
                  {"\"secretIAIVsecretPHsecretQ\""=>
                    {",\"Signature\":"=>
                      {"\"PJ /OW K5secretasyXsecret5A"=>
                        "\"],\"Expires\":[\"1396873090\"],\"Authorization\":[\"\"]}"}}}}}}}}}}},
 "method"=>"PUT",
 "controller"=>"quizzes",
 "action"=>"statements"}
```

IE Edge, Safari, Chrome, and Firefox return my params like this :

```
=> {"registration"=>["27"],
 "Content-Type"=>["application/json"],
 "Signature"=>["secretkqPJGPEsecret01ksecret"],
 "AWSAccessKeyId"=>["Asecret6secretPHsecretQ"],
 "statementId"=>["5919c4f4-b71c-40dd-81dc-ab63cfc824bd"],
 "Expires"=>["1396873699"],
 "Authorization"=>[""],
 "content"=>
  ["{\"object\":{\"definition\":{\"type\":\"Course\",\"name\":{\"und\":\"\"},\"description\":{\"und\":\"\"}},\"id\":\"6LHIJumrnmV_course_id\"},\"verb\":\"attempted\",\"context\":{\"registration\":\"27\",\"contextActivities\":{\"parent\":{\"id\":\"6LHIJumrnmV_course_id\"},\"grouping\":{\"id\":\"6LHIJumrnmV_course_id\"}}},\"actor\":213}"],
 "method"=>"PUT",
 "controller"=>"quizzes",
 "action"=>"statements",
 "quiz"=>{}
```

So my code parses this conveniently doing this :

```
content = params[:content] || params['content']
response = JSON.parse(content.first)
```

And presto! I have a workable piece of content. But with that first aforementioned Hash, I'm not sure how to convert that. Should I just be thinking of using a match/gsub technique to remove all those evil forward slashes? Is there a way to decipher that into something that looks like my latter hash?

Comment: I think you should avoid to fix the error server side, and instead fix it client side, as the error is client side

Comment: IE produces it though. I'm not sure I understand your advice. In any case, because I'm working with a blackbox API ( meaning I can't touch what its producing ).. I just have to deal with whatever crap it's presenting me.

Comment: To help, we'd need to know what is causing IE to behave that way. Please describe the circumstances that trigger that response and show the code. Is it Javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to find that answer. I have a blackbox API ( in Flash ), that I load within an iFrame. Once the app is loaded, it sends a request to my server. If I use IE10 or less, than the paramters it returns are like my mentioned examples. Its not possible for me to adjust or look into the code itself of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your answer, I would parse `key` using the [`escape_utils` gem](https://github.com/brianmario/escape_utils#javascript):

```
require 'escape_utils'

def nested_hash_value(obj,key)
  # nested_hash_value(params, ",\"content\":")
  if obj.respond_to?(:key?) && obj.key?(key)
    obj[key]
  elsif obj.respond_to?(:each)
    r = nil
    obj.find{ |*a| r=nested_hash_value(a.last,key) }
    r
  end
end    

extract  = nested_hash_value(params, ",\"content\":")
key      = extract.keys.first
response = JSON.parse EscapeUtils.unescape_javascript(key).gsub(/^"|"$/,'')
```

This avoids using the evil `eval` thing.

More generally, I think you should build your processing in this way:

```
def smell_of_ie_weirdness?
  # Detects whether the request seems like the one sent by IE 10,
  # something like params keys formatting checking etc.
end

def extracted_response
  if smell_of_ie_weirdness?
    # Do weird stuff
    extract_response_for_weird_ie
  else
    # Be clean and polite
    extract_response
  end
end
```

Comment: Very creative response. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well this gives me an answer.. it's not the best. It's definitely a hack. But I feel like it's the only thing I got.

```
def nested_hash_value(obj,key)
  # nested_hash_value(params, ",\"content\":")
  if obj.respond_to?(:key?) && obj.key?(key)
    obj[key]
  elsif obj.respond_to?(:each)
    r = nil
    obj.find{ |*a| r=nested_hash_value(a.last,key) }
    r
  end
end    


extract      = nested_hash_value(params, ",\"content\":")
key          = extract.keys.first
decoded_hash = key.to_s.gsub(/\\/,'').gsub(/\"/,"'").gsub(/'$|^'/,'').gsub(':','=>')
response     = eval decoded_hash
```

If I do a comparison `==` between the two outputs they return `true` .

Then I just throw it all in a rescue block..

```
begin
  content = params[:content] || params['content']
  response = JSON.parse(content.first)
rescue
  perform_fd_up_IE_fixer # :)
end
```

Comment: What if `params` is `{"{\"statementId\":"=>{"\"b3dsecret9-bsecret741-23secreta806c\""=>{",\"Content-Type\":"=>{"\"application/json\""=>{",\"content\":"=>{"\\\\`malicious_command\\\\`"=>{",\"registration\":"=>{"\"27\""=>{",\"AWSAccessKeyId\":"=>{"\"secretIAIVsecretPHsecretQ\""=>{",\"Signature\":"=>{"\"PJ /OW K5secretasyXsecret5A"=>"\"],\"Expires\":[\"1396873090\"],\"Authorization\":[\"\"]}"}}}}}}}}}}}, "method"=>"PUT", "controller"=>"quizzes", "action"=>"statements"}` (note the `malicious_command` part)

Comment: My thoughts exactly.. I'm stepping back from where I'm working on this and working with the original requests. I realized that the requests inconsistently change shape, and it just doesn't add up.